# Theorem 2.9 rudin functional analysis (application of Baire's theorem)

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I'm reading through the theorem 2.9 (Rudin functional analysis) which states

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological vector spaces, $K$ is a compact convex set in $X$, $\Gamma$ is a collection of continuous linear mapping of $X$ into $Y$, and the orbits $$\Gamma(x) = \left\{ \Lambda x : \Lambda \in \Gamma \right\} $$
>   are bounded subsets of $Y$, for every $x$ in $K$. Then there's a bounded set $B \subset Y$ such that $\Lambda(K) \subset B$ for every $\Lambda \in \Gamma$

The proof goes as follows:

Let $B$ be the union of all sets $\Gamma(x)$, for $x \in K$. Pick balanced neighborhoods $W$ and $U$ of $0$ in $Y$ such that $\bar{U} + \bar{U} \subset W$ put

$$
E = \bigcap_{\Lambda \in \Gamma} \Lambda^{-1}(\bar{U}).
$$
If $x \in K$, then $\Gamma(x) \subset nU$ for some $n$, so that $x \in nE$. Consequently,
$$K = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(K \cap nE).$$
Since $E$ is closed, Baire's theorem shows that $K \cap nE$ has non empty interior (relative to $K$) for at least one $n$.

I don't understand how the Baire's theorem is actually applied here, the hypothesis to apply such theorem we need to have a set $S$ that is either a complete metric space (which I don't see anywhere) or a locally compact Hausdorff space. I guess somehow the latter is exploited, but I don't see how.

Can you give me an insight about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that, by Rudin's definition, all topological vector spaces are Hausdorff. The Baire category theorem is applied to $K$, which is by definition compact, hence compact Hausdorff.

Comment: Isn't "locally compact" different from "compact"? I.e. don't I need to show we have a local base whose members have compact closure? Here $K$ is a compact convex set, isn't necessary a topological vector space, right?

Comment: Pointing this out because the statement of Baire's theorem seems to be valid for "locally compact Hausdorff spaces".

Comment: $K$ is a subset of a Hausdorff space (namely $X$), hence Hausdorff, and compact implies locally compact.

Comment: The question might appear silly, why does compact imply locally compact?

Comment: A space $Z$ is locally compact if each point in $Z$ has a neighborhood with compact closure, and if $Z$ is compact, then it is a neighborhood of each of its points with compact closure.

Comment: In section 1.8. the definition of "locally compact" is only given for topological vector space. Definition for more general spaces doesn't seem to be provided anywhere throughout the textbook. Shall I assume the "local compact" mentioned in the Baire's theorem isn't necessarely about tvs?

Comment: Or are we considering $K$ as a subspace? (topologically speaking).

Comment: $K$ is a topological subspace.  And yes, Baire's theorem applies not only to topological vector spaces, but to topological spaces in general.

Comment: Ok, sometimes the terminology used throughout the book is a bit unclear.

Comment: Just saw Baire's theorem is also proved by Munkres, definition of of "locally compact" is given by chapter 3, section 29.