# Theorem 2.9 Rudin functional analysis - Inferring exists $n$ such that $K \cap nE \neq \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, baire-category

Follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988547/theorem-2-9-rudin-functional-analysis-application-of-baires-theorem).

I realized that question, which I've asked, explains "why" we can apply Baire's Theorem to $K$. It doesn't address however why $\exists n$ such that $K \cap nE \neq \emptyset$, so this question it's just a check (as I'm reviewing my knowledge of Functional Analysis).

According to Baire's theorem such a $K$ is of second category, which means *it is not* a countable union of nowhere dense (so it's of second category) or equivalently the countable intersection of open dense in $K$ is not empty.

However I'm not able to reach the conclusion I want (or maybe I'm just not convinced). I guess I can pick a collection of open dense in $K$ therefore (collection is $\left\{ V_i \right\}$)

$$
K = \overline{\bigcap V_i} = \bigcup K \cap nE
$$

the bit that is confusing me is when I say "I can pick", can I actually pick such a collection as a consequence of Baire's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$K = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K \cap nE$$

and for all $n \geq 1$ we have that $K \cap nE$ is closed in $K$ (since $E$ is closed in $X$). By the Baire category theorem (applied to the compact Hausdorff space  $K$), there is $n \geq 1$ such that $K \cap nE$ has non-empty interior. In particular, $K \cap nE \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: How exactly are you applying Baire's theorem here? That's bit I struggle to get. Why does Baire's theorem imply there's such an $n$?

Comment: Baire category theorem implies that a compact Hausdorff space is not the countable union of closed sets with empty interior (or Baire would imply that the entire space has empty interior which is absurd).

Comment: Why would it imply the entire space has empty interior?

Comment: @user8469759 Suppose that $X$ is a Baire space (a space in which the countable intersection of open dense subsets is again dense, for example locally compact Hausdorff  spaces are such spaces). Suppose that $X= \cup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ where $X_n$ where all $n \geq 1$ are closed sets. Then there must be $n \geq 1$ such that $X_n$ has non-empty interior. To see this, suppose to the contrary that for all $n \geq 1$ the interior of $X_n$ is empty. Then we have $\emptyset = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_n^c$ and $X_n^c$ is open and dense for all $n \geq 1$, contradicting that $X$ is a Baire space.

Comment: Thank you for your patience

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: Hi, sorry... from your last comment. If $X_n$ is closed with empty interior, then $X_n = \partial X_n$. Therefore if $U$ is open in $X$ we have $U \subset X - X_n^\circ$ = $X - (X_n - \partial X_n) = X_n^c \cup \partial X_n$. I can't reach the conclusion that $X_n^c$ is dense.

Comment: Use that $A$ is dense in $X$ if $cl(A)=X$ together with the relation $cl(A)=X\setminus(int(X\setminus A))$

Comment: @user8469759 Did it work out?

Comment: Not really, sorry.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: Is $A$ supposed to be some $X_n^c$ as a starter?

Comment: Yes, tthe idea is that you apply my two facts with $A= X_n^c$. Then you get $cl(X_n^c) = int(X_n)^c = \emptyset^c = X$ so $X_n^c$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110845/discussion-between-user8469759-and--).